# Is there a way to reverse the effect of $a\tan2$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a specific question about reversing $a\tan2$. (I am programmer, sorry for the jargon). I also use the $a\tan2$ function in my example, but I think everybody knows what it means.

> radial = 1.12*PI => transformed = -atan2(cos(radial)∗2,sin(radial)*1.5)

Is there a way to reverse the transformed value to the start radial, without knowing the start radial? This is how codeflow should be

> radial => transform(radial) => transformback(transform(radial)) => radial.

I have searched on the web (incl. stack) but I couldn't find any correct code. Also looked on Wikipedia, but it was overwhelming. My question is more a algebra question I think ;).

Let me know what you think!

Comment: My guess at the meaning of the question.  Suppose $t = -\mathrm{atan2}(2\cos\theta,(3/2)\sin\theta)$, where $\mathrm{atan2}$ is defined by $\mathrm{atan2}(x,y) = \arctan(y/x)$.  Solve the equation for $\theta$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: If this guy is let loose bridges will collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Where do the *2 and *1.5 come from in your transformation?.  Without them you would already have radial=atan2(cos(radial),sin(radial))

The normal inverse of atan2 is the tangent function-it takes in the angle given to atan2 and returns the ratio of $y$ to $x$.  That's the best you will get as atan2 throws away the radius from the origin.

Comment: Tim hasn't been back since June 20 to look and see if there are answers.